# How to delete an portfolio after using initPortf in package "blotter" in R

Tags: r, package, portfolio

When using the function `initPortf` to initialize portfolio in package `blotter` in R,
we can initialize a portfolio, such as:

```
currency("USD")
stock("SPY",currency="USD",multiplier=1)
b.strategy <- "bFaber"
initPortf(b.strategy,'SPY', initDate='1997-12-31')
```

But when we want to initialize the portfolio again, we must delete the portfolio b.strategy first:

```
initPortf(b.strategy, "SPY", initDate = "1997-12-31") : 
Portfolio bFaber already exists, use updatePortf() or addPortfInstr() to update it.
```

the `rm()` could not be used here, when I need to delete it, I have to clear all of the workspace. Is there any function to delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the quantstrat demo scripts do something like this:

```
suppressWarnings(rm("account.bFaber","portfolio.bFaber",pos=.blotter))
suppressWarnings(rm("order_book.bFaber",pos=.strategy))
```